# Sortring in R: Object not found

Tags: r, sorting

I've been following a tutorial regarding ordering output for R dataframes:

https://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html

The problem I'm having is that when I use order the way that is presented in the tutorial, the below code spits out `object not found`. I don't understand why it can't order the dataframe but the print statements seem to be working fine.

The following is the code I'm using:

```
#hospital name is row 2
#state is row 7
#heart attack is row 11
#heart failure is row 17
#pneumonia is row 23
best <- function(state, outcome){
    colNum <- -1

    ##Semi hard coded :(
    if(outcome == "heart attack"){
        colNum <- 11
    } else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
        colNum <- 17
    } else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
        colNum <- 23
    } else {
        stop("invalid outcome")
    }

    raw <-  read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

    if(sum(raw$State == state) <= 0){
        stop("invalid state") 
    }

    rawRelevant <- raw[with(raw, raw[,colNum] != "Not Available" & 
         raw[,7] == state),c(2,colNum)]
    rawRelevant[,2] <- as.numeric(rawRelevant[,2])
    names(rawRelevant) <- c("Hospital", "Rate")
    print(rawRelevant$Hospital)
    print(rawRelevant$Rate)
    data <- rawRelevant[order(Rate,Hospital),]
}
```

Sample Output:

```
> trial <- best("AK", "heart attack")
[1] "PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER" "MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"  
[3] "FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL"      "ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL"        
[5] "ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER"    
[1] 13.4 17.7 15.5 14.5 15.7
Error in order(Rate, Hospital) : object 'Rate' not found
```

Comment: It should be `data <- rawRelevant[order(rawRelevant$Rate,rawRelevant$Hospital),]` That tutorial seems to use a lot of variables that aren't necessarily in data.frames.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68391926

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In R you cannot just pass the column names to the `[.data.table` function, even if they might be imagined to be obviously referring to columns within the data.table being extracted or re-ordered. You need to use either "[" or "$":

```
data <- rawRelevant[ order( rawRelevant$Rate, rawRelevant$Hospital), ]
```

The use of non-specific object names like "data" is discouraged, especially so when they are also the names of R functions as are `data` or `df`. One situation that might arise is that higher up in someones code there might have been an `attach` call for `rawRelevant`, and that would have the side-effect of appearing to promote the column-names to objects. But `attach` causes a lot of confusion since it is not meant for programming, only for interactive use, and so its use is also discouraged.

Notice that the UCLA people used `attach(hsb2)`. Several years ago the UCLA stats websites were advising against R in preference to SAS and SPSS. Now they seem to have come around, but I don't think they are really completely "with the program."

Comment: I've read so many books where the authors use `attach` and it's at about that point that I find a different book.

Comment: At one point there were an endless stream of questions on R-help from persons reading "The R Book" because it was fleetingly popular and  the author used `attach` a lot.

Comment: "In R you cannot just pass the column names to a function". Well, `data.table::data.table(A = c(2, 1))[order(A), ]` works just fine.

Comment: Yes, Grasshopper. That's so-called "non-standard evaluation" which with the emergence of data.table and ggplot and the entire tidyverse has become almost, well, the "new standard". Column names have been given "language" status. This answer written 7 years ago was written in the context of what might be called "classical R". The syntax of packages has been evolving and people didn't seem to like the fact that column names needed to be referred to with character quotes. In computer languages 7 years can be a long time. (I've narrowed the statement so it is now correct in the context of 2021.)