# Why is this code working in the R console, but not as part of an R package?

Tags: r, debugging

This code is working fine:

```
data.table::data.table(A = c(2, 1))[order(A), ]
```

It prints:

```
   A
1: 1
2: 2
```

I can wrap this code inside a function just fine, too (same output):

```
bug <- function() {
    data.table::data.table(A = c(2, 1))[order(A), ]
}
bug()
```

However, putting this function into a package and calling `Bug::bug()`does not work for some reason, giving me

```
Error in order(A) : object 'A' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> [ -> [.data.table -> [.data.frame -> order
Execution halted
```

Here is how to reproduce this problem:

File `DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: Bug
Title: Bug
Version: 0.0.0.0001
Description: Bug
License: GPLv3
Imports: data.table
Encoding: UTF-8
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

File `R/Bug.R`:

```
#' @export
bug <- function() {
    data.table::data.table(A = c(2, 1))[order(A), ]
}
```

Then `cd` into the directory where `DESCRIPTION` is and issue

```sh
R -e "devtools::document(); devtools::install(); Bug::bug()"
```

Comment: What do you have in the `NAMESPACE` file? If nothing, try to include `export(bug)`.

Comment: doesn't import(data.table) also need to be in the NAMESPACE file

Comment: @user2957945 Yes, `importFrom("data.table", "[.data.table")`. But not `"[.data.frame"` and `"order`"`, package `base` is always available.

Comment: @RuiBarradas; although given they are using data.table functionality it is probably best to import the full package

Comment: @user2957945 Yes, I'm limiting the comment to the question.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `devtools::document();` creates `NAMESPACE`. It contains only `export(bug)`, as you suggest in your first comment.

Comment: You should import data.table's functions used in your package.

Comment: @RuiBarradas "Error: object ‘[.data.table’ is not exported by 'namespace:data.table'"

Comment: Try `import(data.table)` in the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, just tried that - that works as a workaround. I prefer specific `importFrom`s, though. Any idea what else I might use? `importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")` also works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data.table` package does some strange non-standard evaluation.  It tries to figure out whether your package wants to support that or not, and in your case, decided "not".

I think this is documented behaviour, but I'd call it a design flaw, if not a bug.

You can force it to support the NSE by putting

```
.datatable.aware <- TRUE
```

somewhere in your package source code.

Comment: See also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2341